# "levied by supporters"

Tags: verbs

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/fact-check-claim-chinese-investment-144905735.html) there is a line saying,

> His is one of many unfounded claims against the company, tied to voting fraud conspiracy theories and **levied by supporters** of President Donald Trump. In response, attorneys representing Dominion Voting Systems have issued notices of litigation to far-right wing media company Newsmax, Rudy Giuliani and others on defamation claims, USA TODAY reported.

I'm quite familiar with the use of such as "levy tax...".

Which definition is used for the above bold part from the below Merriam's definitions?

> transitive verb
>
> 1a: to impose or collect by legal authority
> levy a tax
>
> b: to require by authority
>
> 2: to enlist or conscript for military service
>
> 3: to carry on (war) : wage

Comment: It's #3. Also, be aware of the ridiculous amounts of opinion in something not in the editorial section.

Comment: I find the use strange. I interpret it as metaphorical, like levying a charge or tax, and so increasing your capital.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Thank you^^. I also suspected so but I didn't have confidence. Thank you!

Comment: @ColinFine Oh OK. Got it. It could be such a case. Anyways, thank you!.

Comment: Personally, I think it's an error, and the writer was probably reaching for 'levelled' (or 'leveled' since the source is American). One levels accusations, claims etc. [level sth against/at sb (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/level-sth-against-at-sb)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Did you kindly read the previous line in the link? or did you see the adjective "unfounded" (claims)? I would say if it is a mistake, "supported" would be the alternative choice.

Comment: @Kentaro I read the whole story; 'supported' would not be at all a choice. The claims against the [voting machine] company were levelled by supporters of Donald Trump. Founded or unfounded, claims, accusations, complaints, etc, are levelled against someone or something.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a typing error.